# SQL Server 2008 index approach when using Year()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

I have a table 'customertransactions' with a column 'transactiondate' of type DateTime.

I will be querying it with the following:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) AS totalbal FROM customertransactions WHERE accountcode=?
AND (MONTH(GETDATE())-MONTH(transactiondate)+12*(YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(transactiondate)))>= 3
```

... obviously passing a sanitised parameter for 'accountcode'.

My question is - how do I best create an index to optimise that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "where transaction is more than 3 months old"? Then you code is wrong and should have been `where datediff(m, transactiondate, getdate()) >= 3`.

Comment: Are you sure the query couldn't be better written before you try to adjust indexes? What is the business rule?

Comment: @GSerg Actually, your WHERE clause is not sargable. It should be written: `where transactiondate <= dateadd(month, -3, getdate())`. This will allow an index on `transactiondate` to be considered.

Comment: OK, taking GSerg's suggestion on board it's then just a straighforward non-clustered index on 'transactiondate'?

Comment: @AlanB Yes, but also take RedFilter's suggestion on board.

Comment: If you need this query a lot, you could also create **computed, persisted** columns for the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` - something like `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD TransactionYear AS YEAR(TransactionDate) PERSISTED`. This adds new columns to the table, persists the data into the table structure, and you can index those new columns and these indexes will be used (when useful enough) by the SQL Server Optimizer

Comment: Tip: Save a single value from `GetDate()` in a variable, then use that value repeatedly.  In most cases you do not want to be debugging problems that occur as time changes during query execution, and it lets the optimizer do something more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily, I would consider indexing `accountcode`. Additionally, if you can rewrite your date clause so that it is [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), then you may benefit from indexing `transactiondate` as well.

As always, consider the cardinality of your data, and examine the query plan when adding indexes. There are no hard and fast rules.